# Entity Framework Code First Migration - drop column

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, migration, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When needing to add a new column to a table using Entity Framework Code First Migrations, you simply do something like: "add-migration newColumn", then "update-database". What is the specific command to drop newColumn?

"remove-migration newColumn", then "update-database"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, are you trying to revert a migration or are you trying to simply drop a column that you previously added?

Simple answer, modify your model (by removing the column) and add a new migration. This new migration will include the DropColumn command to remove the column.

If you are trying to revert a migration, you need to:

```
update-database -TargetMigration: "Migration"
```

Where "Migration" is the name of the migration prior to the one you are trying to revert. Additionally, if you need to revert to the original state you can use:

```
update-database -TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

The MSDN article explains this pretty well:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to revert to a previous migration before the column was added.